# Performance difference using std::min or ternary operator?

Tags: c++, c++11

Is there any performance difference in using

```
a = a <= b ? a : b;
```

versus

```
a = std::min(a, b);
```

In the code where I am working the first form is used but the variable names are quite long which makes it hard to read. I would prefer to use the second but not sure if there is any performance difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go for clarity over premature optimization.

Even if there is a performance difference between the two versions[*], it would only matter if this line is part of the overall performance bottleneck: read up on [Amdahl's Law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

[*] It's unlikely that there will be perceptible performance difference anyway. If you really, really want to know, the only way to find out for sure is by constructing some representative benchmarks, building them using your toolchain and running them on your target architecture.

Answer (score 13):

I tested it with gcc -O2 and both produced the exact same assembly. There is no difference at all.

Answer (score 3):

This is how my standard library implementation (gcc5) looks like:

```
template<typename _Tp>
    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
    inline const _Tp&
    min(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
    {
      // concept requirements
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<_Tp>)
      //return __b < __a ? __b : __a;
      if (__b < __a)
    return __b;
      return __a;
    }
```

So, when inlining this function, and with all optimizations turned on, the code for `std::min` is as fast as it gets. Micro-optimizations are usually not the bottleneck in a program.

Comment: A hand written version would probably pass and return by value, which would be easier to optimise.

Comment: @AlanStokes And will be also slightly safer, since if you do `const int& x = min(n+1, n-1);`, you end up with a dangling reference.

Comment: @vsoftco Doesn't the temporary get its lifetime extended to that of `x` in this case?

Comment: Not via return of a function

Answer (score 1):

This is where you need to do some performance analysis.  But, you'll probably find no difference since both statement will probably generate the exact same code (where looking at the assembly code generated can help -- with `g++`, compile with `-S`).

Answer (score 1):

In both clang and gcc (with optimizations enabled), they produce the same assembly:

```
    cmp     esi, edi
    cmovle  edi, esi
    mov     eax, edi
```

Check it out
https://godbolt.org/g/eWsJl9